# drupal cache clear issue

Tags: drupal, memcached

I have the fetched data stored in a variable. This is set in the drupal cache. When i try to reset the cache using cache_clear_all it does not work.

```
$data = getdata();
cache_set($tableid, $data, 'cache', strtotime("midnight + 1 day + 1 hour"));

if(condition){
  cache_clear_all($tableid,'cache',true);
}
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Well first, you are using cache_set() wrong, see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--cache.inc/function/cache_set/6. But that might just be your example code.

You tagged it with memcached, are you using the memcache or cache_router module as backend? Have you checked the issue queue there?

Comment: made the changes, I am using memcache